# Problem with linked list/pointers

Tags: c

I'm currently having an issue with linked list and pointers in C. The problem I'm having is with adding data to a linked list. Currently I have:

```
struct str_pair{ 
char ip  [50] ;
char uri [50] ;
struct str_pair *next ;
};

struct str_pair *it ;

struct str_pair *header = NULL; // Start of linked list
struct str_pair *ptr; // Moves along the list
struct str_pair *ptr2; // Another pointer
struct str_pair *ptr3;

void addData(char *addURI, char *addIP){

    struct str_pair *tmp, *tmp2;

    tmp = (str_pair*)malloc(sizeof(str_pair)); // Create new space in str_pair
    strncpy(tmp->uri, addURI, 49);
    strncpy(tmp->ip, addIP, 49);
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (header == NULL) { header = tmp; }
    else
    {
        tmp2 = header;
        while (tmp2->next != NULL) { tmp2 = tmp2->next; }
        tmp2->next = tmp;
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to do is pass a URL and an IP address through the parameters in which it should add those values into the linked list.

Here is code that calls this function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int incrItems=0;
    int j;

    header = NULL;

    for(j = 1; j < argc; j++)
    {
        char ch=argv[j][0];

        switch(ch)
        {
        case 'A' :
            {
                char *newURI = argv[j+1];
                char *newIP = argv[j+2];
                incrItems++;
                addData(newURI,newIP);
                j=j+2;
                break;
            }

*Snipped the rest as its unnecessary*
```

The problem I'm having is that the passed arguments are not being added to the linked list. No error is shown when compiling.

Comment: What problem do you have exactly?

Comment: You actually forgot to mention your problem!

Comment: The problem is that its not working. The data from passed arguments is not showing in the linked list. No error is shown when compiling the code.

Comment: Is this homework? New user writing linked lists from scratch in C in mid-September?

Comment: @George: "Not working" is not a "problem" description. Make a testcase, narrow down the issue and present a _specific_ question please. This is not debugmycodeplz.com -- it is a site for interesting questions about programming _languages_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(j = 1; j < argc; j++)
    {
    switch(argv[j][0]) { /* no need to copy */
    case 'A' :
            incrItems++;
            /* assert (j+2 < argc); */
            addData(argv[j+1], argv[j+2]); /* no need to copy */
            j=j+2;
            break;
    case 'B' :
    default:
      ...
            break;
        }
     }
```

EDIT: Note: the above is not **the solution**, merely a hint.
Another hint:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void addData(char *addURI, char *addIP){

    struct str_pair *tmp, **hnd;

    tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);
    /* assert (tmp != NULL); */
    strncpy(tmp->uri, addURI, 49); tmp->uri[49] = 0;
    strncpy(tmp->ip, addIP, 49); tmp->ip[49] = 0;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    for (hnd = &header; *hnd; hnd = &(*hnd)->next) {;}
    *hnd = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Hahaha not too bright :), it's late where I am so I'm taking my time to process your "hints". Your help is appreciated :D.

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside a for, why are you incrementing the j variable? Plus, try putting some printf inside the add function to know if the arguments are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Although the nice hints provided by wildplasser, but the code works perfectly fine.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int incrItems=0;
    int j;

    header = NULL;

    for(j = 1; j < argc; j++)
    {
        char ch=argv[j][0];

        switch(ch)
        {
        case 'A' :
            {
                char *newURI = argv[j+1];
                char *newIP = argv[j+2];
                incrItems++;
                printf(" Adding %s %s\n", newURI, newIP);
                addData(newURI,newIP);
                j=j+2;
                break;
            }
        }
     }
printf(" J at end is %d\n",j);

it = header;
if(it != NULL)
do {
        printf(" %s %s\n",it->ip, it->uri);
        it = it->next;
}while(it != NULL);

    }
```